# get status info Windows Media Player (stand-alone application)

Tags: c#, pinvoke, wmp

I want to write an application which gets the status information about a running WMP thread, like playing/paused, shuffle mode on/off, repeat on/off, song title or media file path.

I was using the P/Invoke `SendMessage`-function to "simulate" a click on the play/pause/stop etc. buttons, but I'm unable read the values of labels/text boxes inside the WMP application with `WM_GETTEXT`.
I used Spy++ to get the handles of certain text fields - but they (obviously) change their handle after restarting the WMP.

Does somebody know a answer to this Problem?

It could be anything - P/Invoke or `SendKeys` - but **not** this AxWindowsMediaPlayer, because my application is a console app and I want the status information of the external process - not of my own.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the supported way to automate an application, UI Automation?

Comment: @David Heffernan: no - I didn't try it and I haven't got any experiences in this field. I will gooogle it and look, if I find a way to achieve the effect I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will mark this thread as 'answered'.

I have solved this problem a few months ago, but lost the source code.
The aim of this application is to control the WMP via sshd or telnet.
You can download the binaries here if you want to:

WMP.rar (27 KB)
https://mega.co.nz/#!ug5DySRR!rQlI9OZZ8wYq7yAqaH-KYsmCl9LSaBjNdvqX0g_WDtI

The application is executed via console. You can see the commands by typing >`wmp help`